# Detect and extract separate parts of a larger image

Tags: image-processing

I have a single image (originally in PDF format, but can also be converted to PNG, etc), which consists of multiple small pictures. I would like to have a separate image file (of any format) for each picture contained within this image.

Each picture is in its own box, but the boxes are of different sizes and scattered around the page, so simple grid-based splitting doesn't work. The pictures are not embedded into the PDF as individual images either, so the tools that extract images from PDFs don't seem to work. I could do this manually, but I have about 200 pages to split up so that would take prohibitively long.

Can the community recommend some software which can do this automatically? I would prefer free software, but am able to pay a small amount (maximum ~$20) if necessary.

For copyright reasons, I can't post any of the actual images I want to split up directly. I can, however, post a marketing picture which shows three of them layered on top of each other.

[image: A monster for every season]

Comment: You could try Fred Weinhaus's script http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php